# integral using change of order of $\int _0^9\:\int _{x^{1/2}}^3\cos{(y^3-3y)}\,dy\,dx$?

Tags: multiple-integral, order-of-integration

I was refreshing multiple integral, and I came across with this question:

$\int _0^9\int _{x^{1/2}}^3\cos{(y^3-3y)}\,dy\,dx$

I used change of order since $\cos(y^3-3y)$ cannot be integrated at the current order. I found:

$\int _0^3\int _{0}^{y^2}\cos{(y^3-3y)}\,dx\,dy$

I remember doing a question similar to this but then it was different since when you change order of integration, the lowest value was not 0. It was 1. Had the integration starts from 1 u-substitution would be applicable. But now it is hard.

I have:

${u = y^3 - 3y}$

${du/dy = 3(y^2 - 1)}$

$\int _0^3{y^2}\sin({y^3-3y})dy$

Since, the range was ${0 <= x <= y^2 }$, the zero leaves us with one integral. I know how to work with 1 instead of 0, where I will have:

$\int _0^3{y^2}\sin({y^3-3y})\,dy$ - $\int _0^3\sin({y^3-3y})\,dy$

and factoring:

$\int _0^3{(y^2-1)}\sin({y^3-3y})\,dy$

In the immediate above case, we can just do a simple $u$-substitution.

I don't know how to proceed with when it is zero.

Comment: I'm thinking that $$\int _0^3{y^2}(sin{y^3-3y})dy$$
should really be $$\int _0^3{y^2}\cos({y^3-3y})dy$$

Comment: @WW1 yes, thank you for pointing it out. I am new to the syntax.